# Subgroup of direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider the groups $A=(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $B=(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$. Find every subgroup of the direct product $A \times B$.

I have one suggestion, but I don't know if it is true: Is true that every subgroup is the form $H \times T$, where $H$ is subgroup of $A$ and $T$ is subgroup of $B$?

Comment: No, the conjecture in the second paragraph isn't true. If you look at $\langle 1,1\rangle < A\times B$, the only subgroup of $A$ that it contains is $3\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$, so you can't get $(1,1)$ by adding a subgroup $\{0\}\times \mathbb Z_3$ to it.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Consider the "projection" homomorphisms $\pi_1: A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_2: A \times B \to B$ and recall that the image of a subgroup under a group homomorphism must still be a subgroup. So if $H \subseteq A \times B$ is a subgroup, then $\pi_1 (H)$ must be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_2(H)$ must be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_3$. What are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and given a subgroup of each, can you find a subgroup of $A \times B$ such that its images under the projections are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ you started with? If so, is it unique?